# A Theorem solution that works with Nath

Tags: numbering, theorems, nath

I'd like to use some theorem environment. But I'm using the `nath` package, which is unfortunately incompatible with every solution I've found. I don't need anything very fancy, just the following features:

- (Basic) Automatic numbering of theorems and being able to redefine the words for "Theorem", "Lemma", etc, since I'm not writing in English.
- (Needed) Being able to reference theorems so that `\magicref{that-first-lemma-of-section1}` produces "Lemma 1.1" and not just "1.1".
- (Optional) Being able to give names to important results to that `\magicref{very-important-named-theorem}` produces "Pi's Theorem" instead of "Theorem 3.1.4".
- (Optional) I don't even know exactcly what would be the interface to this, but it's not rare to see texts in which "Theorem 2.71" defines some especial objects, like `\psi_{2.7.1}` that are referenced elsewhere. I'd like to that in a easy way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show an attempt that doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, when trying to extract a minimal non working example (I should had done that earlier) I realized the problem was with the babel package, which should be put before nath. Anyway, I'm still interested on how to accomplish the two (Optional) items using ntheorem. Should I post another question or edit this one?

Comment: Please edit this question

Comment: Why closing? The question is pretty clear.

Answer (score 5):

- Referencing with theorem name and package `ntheorem` can be achieved by defining `\p@<counter>`. It adds a prefix to the counter value used in references.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@lemma}{Lemma~}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test document}

\begin{lemma}
\label{first}
This is the first lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}[Pi's Lemma]
\label{pi}
This is a named lemma.
\end{lemma}

References: \ref{first} and \ref{pi}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

- References to the title of the theorems can be done by package `nameref`. However `nameref` does not yet support `ntheorem`'s theorems. Therefore the internals are patched to get the title in to the reference by defining `\@currentlabelname`. In case of unnamed theorems, the theorem name with number is used as title for `\nameref`. Therefore the example file does not redefine `\p@<counter>` to keep a way to get the number only.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{gettitlestring}% also used by nameref 2009/12/08 or later

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\saved@ythm}{%
  \let\saved@ythm\@ythm
  \def\@ythm#1#2#3[#4]{%
    \GetTitleString{#4}%
    \let\@currentlabelname\GetTitleStringResult
    \saved@ythm{#1}{#2}{#3}[{#4}]%
  }%
}
\@ifdefinable{\saved@xthm}{%
  \let\saved@xthm\@xthm
  \def\@xthm#1#2#3{%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{%
      #3~\csname the#2\endcsname
    }%
    \saved@xthm{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\section{Test document}

\begin{lemma}
\label{first}
This is the first lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}[Pi's Lemma]
\label{pi}
This is a named lemma.
\end{lemma}

References via \verb|\ref|: \ref{first} and \ref{pi}.

References via \verb|\nameref|: \nameref{first} and \nameref{pi}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

"Every solution does not work"? in which manner?

This compiles just fine (TUG TeX Live 2012 frozen)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,nath}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\begin{document}

\begin{test}
$$(\sum_i f_i(x)) $$
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with ntheorem and I thought that amsthm would include amsmath, which conflicts with nath. But do you know if at least the (Needed) item is possible to do using amsthm?